# MySQL Error - Inserting into Table

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I have a little problem inserting into a table, here is the code:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO admin_menu (id, title, type, icon, parent, url, order, append, module) VALUES('', 'powerpoint', '0', 'powerpoint.png', '0', 'powerpoint/config', '0', '0', '0' ) ") or die(mysql_error());
```

it gives me the following error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'order, append, module) VALUES('', 'powerpoint', '0',
>   'powerpoint.png', '0', 'pow' at line 1

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 7):

`order` is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html). Wrap it in backticks

```
... url, `order`, append,...
```

You also shouldn't be using [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php).

> Use of this extension is discouraged. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.

Answer (score 3):

you need to use backticks. order is reserved keyword.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO admin_menu (id, title, type, icon, parent, url, `order`, append, module)
```